# Negative reputation for unknown reason

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-questions, reputation-history

Below is the screenshot of negative rep on a question I was never part of. It is now deleted. I have never seen this question before. Still the reputation is not restored. Is this a reputation system bug?

> [image: -2 Rep]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Almost always, this is a post you edited before you had 2K that was deleted.  You got the +2 for the suggested edit and when the post was deleted, you lost that rep.

Comment: I get it now :) Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You made a suggested edit to that post that was approved, awarding you 2 reputation.

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8139284

The post was deleted, therefore you lost 2 reputation.